# how to change Eclipse-Android project name?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have tried using typical F2 for renaming

but got an error, this change cannot be done.

How do you do that?

Comment: close your Eclipse and end task adb from task manager (if you are using windows os) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to kill all your emulators and rename it again ?

Because it has never been a problem to me.

Have you got a File Explorer opened or anything else that is connected to this project ?